# Ruby easy search for key-value pair in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays

Suppose I have this array of hashes:

```
[
{"href"=>"https://company.campfirenow.com", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"campfire"},
{"href"=>"https://basecamp.com/123456789/api/v1", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"bcx"}, 
{"href"=>"https://company.highrisehq.com", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"highrise"}
]
```

How can I parse the "**href**" value of the hash where **"product"=>"bcx"**

Is there any easy way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Edited the question because it doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
ary = [
  {"href"=>"https://company.campfirenow.com", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"campfire"},
  {"href"=>"https://basecamp.com/123456789/api/v1", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"bcx"}, 
  {"href"=>"https://company.highrisehq.com", "name"=>"Company", "id"=>123456789, "product"=>"highrise"}
]

p ary.find { |h| h['product'] == 'bcx' }['href']
# => "https://basecamp.com/123456789/api/v1"
```

Note that this only works if the element exists. Otherwise you will be calling the subscription operator `[]` on `nil`, which will raise an exception, so you might want to check for that first:

```
if h = ary.find { |h| h['product'] == 'bcx' }
  p h['href']
else
  puts 'Not found!'
end
```

If you need to perform that operation multiple times, you should build yourself a data structure for faster lookup:

```
href_by_product = Hash[ary.map { |h| h.values_at('product', 'href') }]
p href_by_product['campfire'] # => "https://company.campfirenow.com"
p href_by_product['bcx']      # => "https://basecamp.com/123456789/api/v1"
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know .find was a method you could call. Really helps.

Comment: @BrianW: Rule #1 of Ruby Programming: learn the methods of `Enumerable`. Then, learn them again.

Comment: nitpick: find/detect + get has the typical problem of non-match + boom. So in Ruby, having no list-comprehensions built-in, I'd write, when using ick: `ary.detect { |h| h['product'] == 'bcx' }.maybe['href']`. When using facets: `ary.map_detect { |h| h["href"] if h['product'] == 'bcx' }`

Comment: @tokland: Sure, this only works if the element exists. That was an assumption of mine that I didn't state explicitly, thanks for pointing it out.