# How to find and return a hash value within an array of hashes, given multiple other values in the hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this array of hashes:

```
results = [
   {"day"=>"2012-08-15", "name"=>"John", "calls"=>"5"},
   {"day"=>"2012-08-15", "name"=>"Bill", "calls"=>"8"},
   {"day"=>"2012-08-16", "name"=>"Bill", "calls"=>"11"},
]
```

How can I search the results to find how many calls Bill made on the 15th?

After reading the answers to "[Ruby easy search for key-value pair in an array of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584326/ruby-easy-search-for-key-value-pair-in-an-array-of-hashes)", I think it might involve expanding upon the following find statement:

```
results.find { |h| h['day'] == '2012-08-15' }['calls']
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're on the right track!

```
results.find {|i| i["day"] == "2012-08-15" and i["name"] == "Bill"}["calls"]
# => "8"
```

Comment: I'd tried a comma in there before, but your _and_ works perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: @s2t2 you can also use `&&` instad if `and`

Answer (score 1):

```
results.select { |h| h['day'] == '2012-08-15' && h['name'] == 'Bill' }
  .reduce(0) { |res,h| res += h['calls'].to_i } #=> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

A Really clumsy implementation ;)

```
def get_calls(hash,name,date) 
 hash.map{|result| result['calls'].to_i if result['day'] == date && result["name"] == name}.compact.reduce(:+)
end

date = "2012-08-15"
name = "Bill"

puts get_calls(results, name, date)
=> 8
```

Comment: you can use @ARun32 version if you are sure you have only one record per combination

Comment: I do have only one record per combo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, "reduce" or "inject" is specifically for this exact operation (To reduce the contents of an enumerable down into a single value:

```
results.reduce(0) do |count, value|
  count + ( value["name"]=="Bill" && value["day"] == "2012-08-15" ? value["calls"].to_i : 0)
end
```

Nice writeup here:
"[Understanding map and reduce](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/11/understanding-map-and-reduce)"

Answer (score 0):

Or another possible way, but a little worse, using inject:

```
results.inject(0) { |number_of_calls, arr_element| arr_element['day'] == '2012-08-15' ? number_of_calls += 1 : number_of_calls += 0  }
```

Note that you have to set number_of_calls in each iteration, otherwise it will not work, for example this does NOT work:

```
p results.inject(0) { |number_of_calls, arr_element| number_of_calls += 1 if arr_element['day'] == '2012-08-15'}
```